# Problem in using TEXT field in mysql Table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1170

This is very straight problem but I haven't figured out any solution yet.
Scenario is I have 2 table in my DB. Source of 2nd table is dependent on 1st table's SOURCE_URL(can be more than 255 char so I have used TEXT).

```
create table SOURCES (
        SOURCES_PK int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
        SOURCE_URL text not null unique,
        DESCRIPTION varchar(255)
);

create table ASSERTIONGROUP (
        ASSERTION_PK int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
        LABEL varchar(255),
        SOURCE text not null,
        foreign key (SOURCE) references SOURCES(SOURCE_URL)
);
```

I am getting this error-

> BLOB/TEXT column 'SOURCE' used in key specification without a key length

I have seen discussion in this post - [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length).
But can't figure out any solution.
I can remove unique from 1st table but then I can't assign foreign key constraint.

I know that `TEXT` field can't be unique so looking for an alternative.

Comment: What version of mysql? According to the documentation "Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html Also, why not reference the primary key of the first table?

Comment: Thanks AllisconC. Now I am referencing the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to match against a long varchar or blob column you'll need to specify the index length:

```
create table SOURCES (
  SOURCES_PK int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,                    
  SOURCE_URL text not null unique,                    
  DESCRIPTION varchar(255),
  INDEX source_url (source_url(100)) );
//  Key length ----------------^^^
```

**For MyISAM**

> The maximum key length is 1000 bytes. This can also be changed by changing the source and recompiling. For the case of a key longer than 250 bytes, a larger key block size than the default of 1024 bytes is used.

**For InnODB**

> Index key prefixes can be up to 767 bytes. See [Section 12.1.8, “CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)”.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Comment: Thanks for your time Johan. But now I am referencing primary key.

Comment: @Anna using PK's is always best :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly you can not index a whole BLOB and TEXT because index key are limited in length.

You can create FullText index on myasam engine only.

When I need to implement a uniqueness constraint I usually use a specific columns which contains a Hash (SHA or MD5) of the Text, and some code to handle Hash clash.

It is a little bit ugly but it works

Comment: Blob/text columns CAN be indexed, but only a limited subset of the whole field, 767 or 1000 bytes, depending on engine: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html