# Store byte array using Entity Framework 4, MySQL and code first?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hey I'm trying to store a simple `byte[]` using EF 4 MySQL (newest connector) and code-first approach.

Simply doing:

```
public byte[] Thumbnail {get; set;}
```

gives me the following error upon creation:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near

And then it points to what comes right after my `byte[]` declaration.

Anyone got any quick tips for me?

Comment: Did I miss something? Isn't Entity Framework only compatible with SQL Server?

Comment: @Yuck Entity framework is not only compatible with SQL Server, you can see the list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework#Entity_Framework_ADO.NET_providers

Comment: But for code first it's a leaner list

Comment: @Jani but mysql should still be fully supported - as far as I can tell. I chose instead to save my thumbnail as a file, and only store the url - although the other method would be preferred, so I'm leaving the question open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the MaxLength Attribute.

```
[MaxLength(16)]
public byte[] test { get; set; }
```

Note that the above turns it into a tinyblob datatype, [wich can have indexing/primary key problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length). When using migrations it turns into this:

```
AddColumn("dbo.testDB", "test", c => c.Binary(storeType: "tinyblob"));
```

You can use the attribute `column` and set `TypeName` to `"Binary"` if you need indexing/Primary Key.

```
[MaxLength(16), Column(TypeName = "Binary")]
public byte[] test { get; set; }
```

Although the above results in a Binary(1) column for me (it's how I got here).

Edit: To get a correct length binary array, simply add `(16)` after `binary` in the migration file:

```
AddColumn("dbo.testDB", "test", c => c.Binary(storeType: "binary(16)"));
```

Unfortunatly, adding it the the typename of the Column attribute doesn't work.

Edit2: It is possible to get a correct database without needing to edit the migration file by creating a custom MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.

```
internal class CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator : MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override MigrationStatement Generate(CreateTableOperation op)
    {
        MigrationStatement statement = base.Generate(op);

        foreach (ColumnModel column in op.Columns)
        {
            if (column.MaxLength.HasValue)
            {
                statement.Sql = statement.Sql.Replace($"`{column.Name}` binary", $"`{column.Name}` binary({column.MaxLength.Value})");
            }
        }

        return statement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... 4 year old post. Uhm, I have no way of validating this is right, so I'm just gonna take your word for it

Comment: This issue still presents itself (7 years later) in EF Core 2.1 using the first party MySQL Provider. Pomelo fixes this issue, but if it is not a option, one can use the `text` type to store binary data.