# Getting error on Using ALTER CHANGE in MySql

Tags: mysql, blob, alter

I have used this query to alter the table field:

```
 ALTER TABLE `recordstudent` CHANGE `DATE` `DATE` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
   ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'DATE' used in key specification without a key length
```

I am new to this and dont know what to do I googled it but found nothing which I could understand .Please help me to remove this error ,all I want this field as unique.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length)

Comment: I think if the field is unique you must specify a number of chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `UNIQUE` constraint on a column of unbounded size (`TEXT` is of "infinite" length).

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `recordstudent` CHANGE `DATE` `DATE` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

You'll have to pick a size that's big enough for your needs (but no bigger)