# How do I specify an index for a TextField in Django with a MySql backend?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I've got a model defined in Django that looks (in part) like this:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    information = models.TextField(max_length = 32, null = True, db_index = True)
```

However, when I try `syncdb` with a MySql backend, I get `Failed to install index for app.Info model: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'information' used in key specification without a key length")`

How can I fix this?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length

Comment: Why are you using a BLOB for a 32-character field? Use a normal CharField.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is to specify the field as a `CharField`, not a `TextField`.

```
class Info(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length = 32, null = True, db_index = True)
```

Comment: CharField is sufficient here, for max_length = 32, but sometimes it's needed to create text field with no length limit (TEXT in mysql), but with limit for number of chars for index only.