# Django - MySQL (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'my_column' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-mysql

I've updated the Django model field from CharField to TextField.

I got the below error while applying migrations in MySQL.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'my_column' used in key specification without a key length")
```

Django version: `2.2.2`
**Note:** This column in included in `unique_together` in Meta.

Below answers not worked/ not related:

- [how-do-i-specify-an-index-for-a-textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129309/how-do-i-specify-an-index-for-a-textfield-in-django-with-a-mysql-backend)
- [Django MySQL - Setting an index on a Textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187245/django-mysql-setting-an-index-on-a-textfield)

Comment: please provide that model

Comment: It does not really make sense to have a unique index on a text field or a text field be part of a unique index as text fields are supposed to store large amounts of text.

Comment: Index created when it's CharField, it will be removed in next migration