# MySQL unique column string

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, unique, unique-key

Currently I have this table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `twMCUserDB` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mc_userName` text NOT NULL,
  `mc_userPass` text NOT NULL,
  `tw_userName` text NOT NULL,
  `tw_userPass` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want the column `mc_userName` to be unique too (just like `id`), but `mc_userName` must be a string.

I tried to make it also a primary key, but that didn’t work.

When I add data to the table, do I first have to check whether the `mc_userName` already exists? Or is there any built-in function in MySQL that I can use (in the insert query, or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just add `UNIQUE`

```
`mc_userName` text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE `twMCUserDB` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mc_userName` text NOT NULL,
  `mc_userPass` text NOT NULL,
  `tw_userName` text NOT NULL,
  `tw_userPass` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (mc_userName)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: How can i add that UNIQUE to the colum than? i'm using Navicat as database editor, and phpmyadmin, but can't find something that can handle this...

Comment: you can try to alter the table by running this DDL: `ALTER TABLE twMCUserDB ADD UNIQUE tb_uq (mc_userName)`

Comment: That returns this: `[Err] 1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'mc_userName' used in key specification without a key length`

Comment: try changing the databatype to `varchar(100)` since it is username

Comment: or `varchar(50)` will suffice

Comment: That did work, but are there difrnce betwwen text and varchar?

Comment: VARCHAR you can set a limit for how many chars it will accept per record, text is (virtually) unlimited *which you don't necessarily want*)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make 'mc_userName ' the Primary Key instead of id? You will have to change the data type of mc_userName to VARCHAR as described in this post: [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length).  Alternatively, create a composite primary key containing id and username.

If you can't do this because of the design of the database then use the EXISTS keyword in a query.  Have a look here for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: I can't do that, because i get the error `MySQL Error 1170: BLOB/TEXT Column Used in Key Specification Without a Key Length`... And i will take an look at that link

Comment: sorry, i meant that first part... Making the mc_userName the primary key instead of the id.... i get the error i sayed above

Comment: I have made a change to my answer.  Can you change the data type of mc_userName to VARCHAR?

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length

Comment: I tried to change it to var char, making the id not primairy anymore, but only the mc_userName, but then i get this error: `ERROR 1167: The used storage engine can't index column 'mc_userName'

Comment: Don't forget that changing from a Text datatype to a VARCHAR may cause data to be truncated e.g. 'Hello' would become 'Hell' with VARCHAR(4).

Comment: I think exists is indeed the best option. I hoped that there was some kind of simple way to do, but this is fine to...