# BLOB/TEXT column 'bestilling' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql, text, key, longtext

I am trying to make a order system, but I am stuck right now.
In the mysql tabel right now, I am using varchar(255) in a column named "bestillinger", but it can only store 255 chars. So I searched a bit, and remembered that i could use longtext or just text, but now when i try to do it, i get a error saying:

```
#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'bestilling' used in key specification without a key length
```

I have tried to search here and in Google, but got no luck with me.

My MySQL tabel is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bestillinger` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bestilling` TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `accepted` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_bestilling` (`id`,`bestilling`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am using UNIQUE KEY because I am using "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in my PHP part. But don't mind that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is really good explanation how to deal with prefixed indexes: http://code-epicenter.com/prefixed-index-in-mysql-database/

Comment: The solution for me was changing column type from text to varchar(64).  I posted an actual answer but we have trigger happy mods deleting them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can't set a text as a primary key.  Mysql only can Index some characters, and type text could be too big to index.

take a look here:

- http://www.mydigitallife.info/mysql-error-1170-42000-blobtext-column-used-in-key-specification-without-a-key-length/
- [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length)

Comment: How can i then do it? I want to be able to store long text in a column?

Comment: create text index under bestilling and use another colmn as PK, like something with autoincrement.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

From your definition above, and the verbose monologue in this answer below I suggest the following revision:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bestillinger` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `bestilling` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `hashcode` CHAR(32) AS (MD5(bestilling)),  
  `accepted` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_bestilling` (hashcode,bestilling(333))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[Specific to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html), the default max length for a single-column index key is **1000 bytes** long ([767 bytes for InnoDB tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-indexes.html), unless you have innodb_large_prefix set). The same length limit applies to any index key prefix (the first N characters for CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT or first N bytes for BINARY, VARBINARY, BLOB). Note the character versus byte difference; assuming a UTF-8 character set and the maximum of 3 bytes for each character, you might hit this limit with a column prefix index of more than **333 characters** on a TEXT or VARCHAR column. In practice, 333 tends to be a good max for me.

[Similarly in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx), there is a 900-byte limit for the maximum total size of all index key columns.

But that only uses the first characters of your TEXT as your key, with the obvious collisions imminent.

In the accepted answer, the suggestion is to use a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). A FULLTEXT index is specially designed for text searching, and it has not-so-good performance for INSERT/DELETE since it maintains an N-gram over the vocabulary of the column records and stores the resulting vector. This would work if every operation were to use text search functions in a where clause...but not for a unique index. There is also both a primary key and a unique key defined on 'id', which seems redundant or I miss the intent.

Instead, I suggest a computed hash. you'd be correct to point out there is a chance (Birthday Paradox) that there will be a collision with a hash, so a UNIQUE index alone isn’t enough. We'll couple it with a column prefix index, as described above, to give us faith in the uniqueness.

I gather the intent of your ID column is to allow proper foreign key referencing from other tables. Quite right, but then that would be the more useful primary key for this table. As well, int(11) refers to the display width of the column, not the underlying value. I put an unsigned auto_increment on 'id' as well, to clarify its role for the larger audience.

And that brings us to the proposed design above.

Comment: I got such error for type text. The length was set to 100. Column name was 'email'. After changing its type to varchar the error is gone .

Comment: I have got this error message "Key/Index cannot be defined on a non-stored computed column"
Just wandering if this could be related to a pay wall issue ?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bestillinger` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bestilling` TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `accepted` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_bestilling` (`id`,`bestilling`(767))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**767** is the limit in mysql while dealing with blob/text indexes

Ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the following example will best explain this problem.

I got the problem because I was trying to set a text field to UNIQUE. I fixed the problem by changing data type of email(TEXT) to email(VARCHAR(254)).

```
mysql> desc users;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname       | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname       | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uname       | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contact     | bigint(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| profile_pic | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(20) | NO   |     | admin   |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE(email);
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'email' used in key specification without a key length
mysql> 
mysql> ALTER  TABLE users MODIFY email VARCHAR(254);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE(email);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc users;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uname       | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(254) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| contact     | bigint(12)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| profile_pic | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | admin   |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: screen-capture]

Try to use all ***column*** length in ***varchar***. Text should be not allowed because of size.

Comment: I would advice to add a code example with your answer.

Comment: I try to insert image . Please check it out.