# make text column as unique key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique-key

i want to make a table in `MySQL` server with `mediumtext` column as `UNIQUE KEY`

```
CREATE TABLE `parts` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` mediumtext NOT NULL,
      `display_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
       UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but this made an error

```
    BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length
```

when I change the type of `name` to varchar .. it works!

can you tell if i can to make text column as `UNIQUE KEY`

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length

Comment: thanks @Tarek but that solution force me to use varchar .. and i want to use a type allow me to insert strings longer than 255 characters

Comment: You might add a length, like `UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`(100)),` if the first 100 were unique.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Basically you can not use `Text` column as `UNIQUE` key. Because practically such a big column will not be unique and there might be a chance of more duplicates. So go for `hashing` method and use that output as a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Note that technically this is not a solution, because two different text values may generate the same hash - ie a [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science). To be *sure* of keeping the values unique you would have to store the whole string too and *not* have a unique index on the hash column.

Comment: Here is a more deep answer for who want to really understand why mysql behave like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1827099/5677103

Comment: @Bohemian But practically speaking, the chances that this collision would occur given that we use a decent hashing algorithm would be very very low, so it would be a good pragmatic solution wouldn't it?

Comment: @Javascriptonian it depends on the population size and the hash algorithm. For example, when using a 32-bit hash result, at around 70K individuals, there's a 50/50 chance of a collision between any two individuals.

Comment: Does not work with mysql, but with mariadb:
https://gist.github.com/BacLuc/0ffb97c8d32b1190b649a955134d0625

Comment: "So go for hashing method and use that output as a UNIQUE constraint." seems to be from another planet as no one talks about hasing before. Downvote for that.

Answer (score 27):

The limit of 255 for varchar length no longer applies. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

Unique indexes must have a known maximum length (a requirement of mysql due to its internal implementation), so use varchar with a large enough value to fit your longest expected value, eg

```
...
`name` varchar(65535) NOT NULL, -- for example 
...
```

Comment: Ok but you cannot create a unique key on a varchar(65535) can you?

Comment: @darma no, not *indexed* columns. The [maximum size for a column with a unique index is varchar(767)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15157227/256196)

Answer (score -2):

I know this is very old but in case anyone else wants to, you can make a varchar or text column unique, you just have to do it after the table creation.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meeting;
CREATE TABLE meeting (
    meeting_id int(11) UNSIGNED UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    meeting_name varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX meeting ON meeting(meeting_name);
```