# index large amount of url as a directory structure

Tags: algorithm, filesystems, distributed-computing

We have a scenario where we get tons of urls from customers, the urls are organized in arbitrary levels like : xxx.com/levelA/levelB/levelC/...levels.../xxxx we are trying to use this data and build a query system that can answer what urls are under any given level. for example, getAll("abc.com/test/sub/"), should give me all the urls that's been recorded that has "abc.com/test/sub/" as prefix, abc.com/test/sub/a.data, abc.com/test/sub/sub2/data etc.

This appears to be similar to a file directory structure. My question is, is there any existing open source project that can help handle such scenario. requirement is :

- real time system.
- high write/read throughput.
- distributed and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions you didn't answer:

- What is a *high write/read throughput*? anything which an RDMS couldn't handle? What is your expected ratio of reads VS writes?
- Why do you want to have a distributed system? Any particular reason?
- How long are the strings an average and maximal?

Are you sure a simple MySQL, PostgreSQL, or any other commercial database (Oracle, SQL Server, ...) won't be enough?

Here is a question about [MySQL varchar index length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157227/mysql-varchar-index-length). I've encountered the same limitation of 255 characters also in SQL Server so I assume similar restrictions will exist for other RDBS. However there is nothing easier than just calling

```
SELECT url FROM url_list WHERE url like 'abc.com/test/sub/%'
```

There is also MongoDB which can be easily distributed and allows to use [Regular Expressions in queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). Together with an index you could perform a similar request as in SQL. You would need to benchmark this specific case for yourself to see if there is a performance difference, and which system has it.

Otherwise, there would be still [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.org/) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) which offer Views, which are basically made for something similar since they are built via MapReduce. However those take few seconds, up to a minute to be updated. So it isn't really fitting if you want to request the URL right after you've inserted it.