# MySQL INDEX Varchar Field 500 for urls

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I am building a multilingual web application.

Urls stored in database like:

```
id_url          bigint(18)
id_map          int(11)
id_entity       bigint(18)
active          tinyint(1)
lang            varchar(8)
path            varchar(500)
path_ids        varchar(50) 
full_path_ids   varchar(50) 
created_at      datetime
```

My question is about `path` indexing. I need to make search only `LIKE '$str%`. I don't need `LIKE '%$str'`.

Index is : `idx_url_path    BTREE   No  No  path (255)  22  A   No`

It automatically degraded to `255`.

Any idea on how to get things done?

Comment: See this SO question -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157227/mysql-varchar-index-length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html

> By default, an index key for a single-column index can be up to 767
>   bytes. The same length limit applies to any index key prefix. See
>   Section 13.1.13, “CREATE INDEX Syntax”. For example, you might hit
>   this limit with a column prefix index of more than 255 characters on a
>   TEXT or VARCHAR column, assuming a UTF-8 character set and the maximum
>   of 3 bytes for each character. When the innodb_large_prefix
>   configuration option is enabled, this length limit is raised to 3072
>   bytes, for InnoDB tables that use the DYNAMIC and COMPRESSED row
>   formats.

So, assuming you are using the InnoDB engine, you can't index 500 characters unless you enable the `innodb_large_prefix` configuration option, and your table is using `DYNAMIC` and `COMPRESSED` row formats:

innodb_large_prefix:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix

DYNAMIC row format:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_dynamic_row_format

COMPRESSED row format:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_compressed_row_format