# SQL error: 1170

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, maxlength

I am getting the following error when running the below code...what is wrong with it?

> Error Code:1170. BLOB/TEXT column 'message" used in key specification without a key length.

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Sun Jun  4 21:25:42 2017
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
    USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `updates_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `first_name_UNIQUE` (`first_name` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `last_name_UNIQUE` (`last_name` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `password_UNIQUE` (`password` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `created_at_UNIQUE` (`created_at` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `updates_at_UNIQUE` (`updates_at` ASC))
      ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`messages`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`messages` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `users_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `message` TEXT NOT NULL,
      `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      INDEX `fk_messages_users_idx` (`users_id` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `users_id_UNIQUE` (`users_id` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `message_UNIQUE` (`message` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `created_at_UNIQUE` (`created_at` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `updated_at_UNIQUE` (`updated_at` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_messages_users`
        FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
      ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`comments` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `users_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `messages_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `comment` TEXT NOT NULL,
      `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      INDEX `fk_comments_users1_idx` (`users_id` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_comments_messages1_idx` (`messages_id` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `users_id_UNIQUE` (`users_id` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `messages_id_UNIQUE` (`messages_id` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `comment_UNIQUE` (`comment` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `created_at_UNIQUE` (`created_at` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `updated_at_UNIQUE` (`updated_at` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_comments_users1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_comments_messages1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`messages_id`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`messages` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Here is a link that might help.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length)

Comment: You may use full text search index on large text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB index maximum length is 767 bytes by default.

When you declare your unique index on your TEXT column, which has a maximum length of 65535 bytes, it exceeds the maximum index length by a lot.

```
UNIQUE INDEX `message_UNIQUE` (`message` ASC),
```

You can enable `innodb_large_prefix` which makes it possible to make an index of 3072 bytes, that's also much too small for a complete TEXT column.

You can us a prefix index for a TEXT column, but that's not a good solution to enforce uniqueness.

```
INDEX `message` (`message`(255) ASC),
```

You should reconsider whether you need a unique constraint on a TEXT column.

See also:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16474039/20860

Answer (score 0):

It is rare for a table to have 6 unique keys.  Even 2 is rare; 1 (the `PRIMARY KEY`) is typical.

`UNIQUE` is two things... an index and a uniqueness constraint.  As Bill points out, a "prefix" index can achieve a form of indexing.  Uniqueness is more complex.  If you really need that, then we can discuss it.

A uniqueness constraint on a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` is risky because there (usually) could be two events happening in the same second.  It is also rare to need a uniqueness check on "continuous" values like that.  (Ditto for `FLOAT`.)

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful! :)