# MySql 5.7, maximum varchar column length is 768?

Tags: mysql

MySql ver 5.7.28, following sql fails with error: "Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes". But when changing 769 to 768 then it works well. Why this happens?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `items` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` VARCHAR(769) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57005/why-are-innodbs-index-keys-limited-to-767-bytes help?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157227/mysql-varchar-index-length

Comment: simply  ...  769  x 4  (utf8mb4) = 3076  > 3072 ...   768  x 4  (utf8mb4) = 3072