# Android SQLite table creation failure

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am writing tests for my database and right now the table below is not building and the test is failing with this SQL command being built: " CREATE TABLE location (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,location_setting TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, city_name TEXT NOT NULL, coord_lat REAL NOT NULL coord_long REAL NOT NULL  ); ". I am pretty certain there is some syntax error yet I am new to databases in android and honestly need help.

Table creation:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                LocationEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT + " REAL NOT NULL " +
                LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG + " REAL NOT NULL " +
                " );";
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add ',' after every column like this just leave the last.

```
    final String SQL_CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            LocationEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
            LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG + " REAL NOT NULL" +
            " );";
```

Comment: yup OP missed a comma before last field :) good catch

Answer (score -1):

You can **not** use `TEXT` with `UNIQUE`.

For more info: [make text column as unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033378/make-text-column-as-unique-key).

You can try `VARCHAR` or think of a different implementation to reach your goal.

Bye

Comment: He's asking for SQLite not MySQL. In SQLite you can create TEXT + UNIQUE column definitions.