# Sequelize datatype TEXT not working with mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sqldatatypes

I am using sequelize ORM with mySQL database.

I have a model with attribute type ***[TEXT](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#data-types)*** as :

```
description: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            unique: true
        },
```

When I am trying to create table for the corresponding model, its giving an error message as :

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError:
> ER_BLOB_KEY_WITHOUT_LENGTH: BLOB/TEXT column 'description' used in key
> specification without a key length

This worked fine when used with postgreSQL.
Possible reason for this error which i could think of can be that mySQL doesn't support TEXT datatype and therefore, i have to specify it as LONGTEXT.

If I am thinking correct or is there some other reason for the same, if someone can help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using `unique: true` with data-type `TEXT`. You can not use it. Do you delete `unique: true` and try again?

Comment: Ah - well spotted!  I forgot mySQL does not support TEXT UNIQUE - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033378/make-text-column-as-unique-key

Comment: Yeah. Thanks esmrkbr , it worked.
and @GeekyDeaks , why have you removed your answer, that was also helpful.

Comment: Ok - I'll put it back in if you think it helps! :)

Answer (score 12):

esmrkbr is correct, mySQL does not accept UNIQUE KEY on a TEXT field, you need to use VARCHAR instead (see: [make text column as unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033378/make-text-column-as-unique-key)).  That being said, depending on the Database being used, you may need to explicitly specify a size for a TEXT (or BLOB) type.  The documentation (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/) is pretty terse on this point and other than a link to the code, currently only has the following information:

> An (un)limited length text column. Available lengths: tiny, medium,
>   long

You can pass the size as a string argument to the type. For example, to have it defined as `LONGTEXT` you will need:

```
description: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT('long')
        },
```

The code in lib/data-types.js has the following mapping to SQL for TEXT (there is a similar one for BLOB also):

```
TEXT.prototype.toSql = function() {
  switch (this._length.toLowerCase()) {
  case 'tiny':
    return 'TINYTEXT';
  case 'medium':
    return 'MEDIUMTEXT';
  case 'long':
    return 'LONGTEXT';
  default:
    return this.key;
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks @GeekyDeaks but still the same error is coming.

Comment: Hi @PrernaJain, with logging enabled what SQL does it output for the CREATE TABLE?

Comment: thanks for the well explanatory answer.
and yea i did not understand what you are asking, can you just explain it a bit more.
@GeekyDeaks

Comment: Hi @PrernaJain, by default Sequelize should output all SQL generated to console.log() so you can check it's doing the right thing.  But if nothing is output, take a look at the following Q/A for some hints on how to get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427501/how-can-i-see-the-sql-generated-by-sequelize-js.

Answer (score 0):

Define as string like this:

```
var filters = sequelize.define('filters', {
 description: { 
  type: DataTypes.STRING, 
  validate: { notEmpty: true }
 }
}
```

Comment: doesn't DataTypes.STRING translate to varchar?