# Datatype for country in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a database for myself and I have a registration form that asks people for their name, password, email, mobile, age, and location. It's hopefully going to be like a dating site.

So far I have (for my database)

```
create table members(
    user VARCHAR(16),
    password VARCHAR(16),
    email VARCHAR(320),
    mobile VARCHAR(15),
    age INT(3)
    #location ???
    INDEX(user(6));
)
```

**EDIT** **forgot to ask the question**

What datatype should be used for the `location` and does the database look safe enough?

The location is by country and is selected by a drop-down menu.

Comment: You missed to ask a question :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks! Completely forgot :)

Comment: Is "location" only the country, or a more detailed location?

Comment: If by `location` you mean a country, then use a foreign key to the `countries` table.

Comment: If it's only the country you want to store, I would suggest a char(2) datatype, to only store the Alpha-2 ISO code for the country: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 then as Paul suggested, have a table with all countries in them. Handy also if you want to provide a list of countries for the user to choose from.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question further, it's been a long day and I keep forgetting things :)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you think I should create a countries table, there is a drop-down menu for the users to select from

Comment: @MicKri you think I should create a countries table, there is a drop-down menu for the users to select from

Comment: Yes, check Pauls answer to create a table with countries. That table should match your dropdown of available countries. Hopefully, the option value you get from your countries dropdown is the 2-letter ISO country code. And another thing... You should not store the password in plain text, you should always encrypt it properly before storing, which means your varchar(16) field is not enough.

Comment: @MicKri I know this might sound stupid on my part, but what datatype would you give the password?

Comment: Se Schwerns excellent answer for details...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *Does the database look safe enough?*

No. And it's going to take a bit to explain.

Let's start with all those limits. Over-enthusiastic use of column limits is a very common problem.

How those limits work is often misunderstood, for example you asked about security, or you might think you're saving space. The real problem is it hard codes unnecessary limits about how the rest of the software behaves into the database, and your limits are pretty stingy.

You asked whether this makes the table more secure. Column limits aren't really about security, though I guess they theoretically keep someone from filling up your disk, but that's not what the limits you have are about.

For example, you have passwords limited to 16 characters. That's not a decision the database should be making, but a security consideration. When you're looking into password security later on, you'll find that 16 character passwords are barely adequate. You want something more like 64 or 128, and that will require an expensive `alter table`.

More importantly, you're storing passwords in the clear. This is a big security problem.

Then you've got email (presumably email addresses) set to 320 characters?! That's a hell of an email address! But users only get 16 for their names?

One common misunderstanding is that these limits reduce the amount of disk used. They don't. `varchar` will only store as much as necessary for that row. `age INT(3)` doesn't use less space than `age INT`, it's a fixed size. <strike>Ok, it makes sure that you don't have any 12938 year olds on your dating site</strike> It doesn't even do that. It's just how many fields get displayed which is ***definitely*** not something that should be in your schema. MySQL does some strange things.

You could use an [`unsigned tinyint`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) which stores from 0 to 255 in 1 byte... but once you're worrying about individual bytes it gets silly. And this is all moot, don't store their age at all. Store their birthday. Because people get older.

---

Enough about the wrong way to use limits, what's the right way?

Limits are for enforcing data integrity (and technical limitations, see the comments). That's about it. You want to make a schema that's flexible enough to support whatever your application wants to become, while also ensuring that the data is what it says it is without having to constantly second guess it.

A better schema might look like this:

```
create table members(
    id primary key auto_increment,

    username varchar(64) unique,
    password_hash varchar(128),
    email varchar(64) unique,
    mobile varchar(32),
    birthday datetime,

    location integer references(locations),

    index(birthday)
)
```

Your table was missing a primary key and that's a big problem. Usernames can change, and you don't want everything that refers to that user to break if it does. Instead, use a simple auto incrementing integer. "But I won't let users change their names!" Yeah, remember what I said about hard coding limits on the software into the data model? How you build your schema has effects for years.

Originally I pulled all the limits off the fields and switched them to unlimited `text`. None of them have a compelling reason for a limit. Unless you have a really good reason, just use `text` or `varchar`. Limits are handled in the data model, changeable by the programmers and designers. A `text` or `varchar` field will only use as much space as it needs.

...but @PaulSpiegel pointed out in the comments that [MySQL's has limitations on how big a field it will index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033453/14660). I'm used to Postgres which has no such limits. So I switched them to `varchar` and picked generous limits. Technical limitations can be a reason to use a limit.

`username` (not `user` because that can refer to the entire user, not just their name) and `email` have been marked `unique`. This is about data integrity, you don't want two people with the same username, and you want to make sure each account has a single point of contact (you might argue this is putting behavior in the database, and you might be right, but it's easier to remove a unique index than to add one).

Then we come to the glaring security problem. ***NEVER STORE PASSWORDS!*** Ever. Ever ever ever. Instead, store a hash of the password. If you don't know what I'm talking about, stop right now and read [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Instead of storing the `age`, we store their `birthday` as a `datetime`. Storing a user's age isn't looking ahead, what happens next year? With their birthday you can calculate their age, and even give them birthday presents! By storing it as a `datetime` you can do all sorts of date calculations on it using [MySQL's confusing date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

And you asked about what to do with location. Location can mean a lot of things, and it can get pretty complicated. This isn't a decision you need to make right now, so it's best to make it so it can be expanded and changed later. Put it in its own table, and reference it with a foreign key. We'll come back to it later, which is the whole point.

Finally, indexes. There's no need to be so skimpy with your disk space that you're only storing the first 6 characters of a username! Looking people up by username is going to be very, very common, give it a full index. But we don't need one, declaring a column `unique` gives it an index.

Indexes can improve query performance, but they can also eat disk space and slow down inserts. Rather than go crazy with the indexes up front, wait until you see what queries you're going to make and what the performance is like. The only explicit index I've put in is `birthday` because I'm pretty sure a dating site is doing to want to limit by age.

---

The missing piece here is your data model. This is the code on top of your data, for example a Member class. It would handle all the things a member can do, including access to the database and what the limitations should be. The model is the only thing that touches the database, the rest of the code calls methods on the model. This lets the database change without worrying about affecting the entire project.

This is known as Model-View-Controller or MVC and it's the basic way data driven applications are coded these days. [Ruby On Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is a good example. Look into MVC.

---

Ok, location. We've made `location` its own table. That makes it an abstract concept rather than some hard coded fields in the `members` table.

Location can get really complicated really fast. So we'll keep it pretty simple. Start with some basic information that other users are going to want to know: who's nearby. The minimum is postal code and country, you can figure a lot out from that. You'll probably also want to keep the city and state, because that's another way people want to locate people.

```
create table locations (
    id integer primary key,

    city text,
    province text,
    country text,
    postal_code text
);
```

Make a Location model to encapsulate and manage the locations data.

Now you can go into as much detail as you like with managing location data without messing up your members table. You can do what [@PaulSpiegel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194046/14660) suggested and make a table of all the countries and their names to reference in the rest of your code and to ensure they're using a real country (data integrity again). You can use their postal codes to get their city and province. You can store GPS data if they'll give it to you.

---

So, uhhh... if you're just starting out this is probably going to seem overwhelming. Data modelling is complicated. It's not necessarily hard, just there's a lot of moving parts and things to consider so your application isn't limited by your schema. You'll probably have to make a few applications with overly simplistic schemas to really understand.

Let's see if I can boil it down.

- Have a simple primary key.
- Avoid column limits.
- Never, ever store passwords in the clear.
- Push complexity off into its own table.
- Store what you can derive more from (birthday, postal code).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed informion! Greatly appretiated :)

Comment: Two points: 1) "it makes sure that you don't have any 12938" - It doesn't. `INT(3)` is technically the same as `INT(10)`. `3` is only the display length (e.g. used for ZEROFILL). But you can use `TINYINT`. 2) AFAIK you cannot define a unique index on a `TEXT` column without lentgh. Thus `email` length should be limited. But overall - great article :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't use MySQL, I use Postgres, so details about MySQL are appreciated and go ahead and edit any technical gaffes. If `text` can't be made unique, use `varchar` without a limit.

Comment: @Schwern it's not about the type (VARCHAR or TEXT). MySQL has a limit for an index key length (usually 768 bytes) and denies any index definition which might exceed that limit.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `countries` table which will store all countries you want to support.

```
code CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE

code | name
=====|=====
  FR | France
  GB | United Kingdom
  US | United States of America
  .. | ...
```

You can find *ISO 3166-1* codes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Use this table to create the drop-down menu.

In your members table you define the column

```
country_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL
```

It should be a foreign key referencing the `countries` table

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_members_countries (country_code) REFERENCES countries(code)
```

Comment: So should I replace `location` to `country`?

Comment: @smithster Why call it location if it is a country? And why call it country if it's in fact a country code? Give every column the name which describes the stored values in the best way.

Comment: Yes :-) That what I would do.

Comment: Rather than making up your own country codes and names, use [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). You can find lists of country codes and names to populate your table.

Comment: @Schwern You are right. But I didn't write anywhere not to use standard codes or names.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That was directed at anyone reading this answer, and a suggestion to add it in. I've seen it too many times.

Comment: @Schwern Added that info. Maybe i didn't see anough strange things. So thanks.