# mysql column should support input length of 1024 character

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

I have a column `dn` which used to support till `varchar(290)`. 
Now it should support input till `1024` characters.

As far I know we have a varchar limit till `767`.

I tried changing the variable type to text but I am getting the below error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `parent1` MODIFY column `dn` text;
```

> ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'dn' used in key specification
>   without a key length

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `parent1` MODIFY column `dn` text(1024);
```

> ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'dn' used in key specification
>   without a key length

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `parent1` MODIFY column `fdn` longtext(1024);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(1024)' at line 1

Here are the indexes:

```
> SHOW keys from parent1; 
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Index_type | NULL | 
| parent1 | 0          | PRIMARY  | 1            | parent_id   | A | 0 | NULL | NULL | BTREE | | 
| parent1 | 0          | id_dn    | 1            | id          | A | 0 | NULL | NULL | BTREE | 
| parent1 | 0          | id_fdn   | 2            | dn          | A | 0 | NULL | NULL | BTREE
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827063/4275342)

Comment: Reference: [MySQL Error 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT Column Used in Key Specification Without a Key Length](http://www.mydigitallife.info/mysql-error-1170-42000-blobtext-column-used-in-key-specification-without-a-key-length/)

Comment: Can you add output of `SHOW KEYS FROM parent1`?

Comment: It's best to edit your question when you add information. The formatting possibilities in comments, well, they suck. I put your index information into your question.

Answer (score 1):

After version 5.0.3 (a *long* time ago) MySQL began supporting `VARCHAR(65535)`.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html

(`CHAR(255)` for fixed-length character strings is indeed the limit.)

The 767 value you mention is the longest allowable index key prefix. That is, if you create an index on a column of type `VARCHAR(768)` or more, you must index only a prefix of the column. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html . The same is true of indexes on `text` (CLOB) columns.

So, when you define any index on such long columns, you need to define it as a prefix. So, if you have this column definition in your table.

```
  dn VARCHAR(8192)
```

you'll need this index creation command or something like it.

```
ALTER TABLE parent1 ADD INDEX id_fdn (dn(767));
```

To alter your table to make that column wider, you first should drop any indexes mentioning that column, then alter the table, then recreate the indexes with the prefix.

There's no need to switch from `VARCHAR()` to `TEXT`, and indeed you should not do that because retrieval will be a little slower if you do.

Also, doing this schema change is enough of a pain in the neck that you might want to add extra characters to future proof the table.

So, something like this will do the trick for you.

```
ALTER TABLE parent1 DROP INDEX id_fdn;
ALTER TABLE parent1 MODIFY COLUMN dn VARCHAR(4096);
ALTER TABLE parent1 ADD INDEX id_fdn (dn(750));
```

What is the search consequence of a prefix index? Not much. The search processing  will use as much of the index as it can, then compare the actual value if necessary.