# How to enforce UNIQUEness of spatial columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-index

Using the `MyISAM` storage engine in MySQL, I'd like to enforce the uniqueness of a `POLYGON` column in a table. Basically if I attempt to insert a duplicate, I want it to result in an error, or simply be ignored. With traditional column types this can be accomplished using the `UNIQUE` keyword, but with a spatial column this leads to errors like:

`ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'bounding_box' used in key specification without a key length`

coming from this table definition:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quadrants (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    bounding_box POLYGON NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    centroid POINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    SPATIAL KEY bb_idx(bounding_box),
    SPATIAL KEY centroid_idx(centroid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;`

Is it possible to enforce uniqueness for spatial datatypes in MySQL?

***EDIT:*** It has been suggested that this is a duplicate of [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063) but I believe it is different. That question and its answers make no mention of spatial datatypes. I'm left to infer that `POLYGON` is actually stored as `BLOB` and thus subject to similar constraints. But I still don't know if there is any other way to enforce uniqueness of `POLYGON`---or whether there are practical workarounds if that is not the case.

The other question addresses the same error, but in a different enough context that I feel a separate question is useful.

Comment: there is no any search efforts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length)

Comment: Check: [11.5.3.6 Creating Spatial Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) and [13.1.11 CREATE INDEX Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

Answer (score 0):

As spatial columns are stored like blob columns, you should create two indexes: a non spatial index with a length for exact queries/uniqueness, and a spatial index for range queries. Furthermore, if your polygons aren’t overlapping, a very small length will be enough.