# mysql #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql

I am try to execute the below SQL and it is given the error above

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oic_assemblyman_data` (
`id` bigint( 100 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`firstname` varchar( 300 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
`lastname` varchar( 300 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
`email` varchar( 300 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`phone` varchar( 300 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`office_latitude` varchar( 20 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`office_longitude` varchar( 20 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`website_welcome_address` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`website_header_color` varchar( 15 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`website_footer_color` varchar( 20 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`about_yourself` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
`password` varchar( 100 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY `email` ( `email` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Could someone point out what is causing the problem

Comment: The error is self explanatory. The length of the key is more than the accepted length. Can you post the key?

Comment: the primary key is "id bigint( 100 )".

Comment: Use a length of `255` for your varchars instead of 300

Comment: @juergend Since the max key length is 767, why would 300 bytes be a problem?

Comment: Thanks @juergen d. 254 worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: your query runs fine on my mysql 5.7.9 ...

Comment: @Barmar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1827099/575376

Answer (score 4):

change your email to varchar(255) should works. i think it using utf-8 encoding which max 3 bytes per character, then 767/3=255...2
so you can set max length to 255