# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'message' used in key specification without a key length")

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am trying to create a model using `django 1.11` and `mysql`(latest) as my backend using `mysqlclient`. I have searched various blogs and docs but was still not able to find my solution.
This is my code Posts.models.py
Please forgive the indentation error here if any.

```
class Post(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     message=models.TextField()
     group=models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name='posts',
     null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.message

     def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single',kwargs{'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

     class Meta:
         ordering=['-created_at']
         unique_together=['user','message']
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length

Comment: @SagunShrestha no it's not , as that person is using that field as a primary key but it's not the case here...

Comment: It's very similar to the duplicate question. You have `message` in `unique_together`, but MySQL can't create the index because it's a `TextField`. You can either remove it from `unique_together`, or change it (e.g. to `models.CharField(max_length=200)`).

Comment: @Alasdair Ok thanks got it, but just in case what to do when i have to index full text field.(CharField is not option as it is very small field from my project perspective)

Comment: @SagunShrestha that's mysql while we are trying to code a solution in Django.

Answer (score 1):

Set length to the text field. It did work for me. Like

```
models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```