# Change string to text type in Laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I have create a table **stack_links** as below

```
Schema::create('stack_links', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('site_key');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('path_run')->nullable();
            $table->integer('state');
            $table->integer('parent')->nullable();
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(['site_key', 'url']);

            $table->index(['site_key']);
            $table->index(['state']);
            $table->index(['parent']);
            $table->index(['url']);
        });
```

Now i want to change url column to text type. So i have tried this

```
 $table->text('url')->change();
```

Hower it return this err

```
1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'url' used in key specification without a key length
```

After searching, i found that the err because url is indexed([MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length)). So i remove index but it still the same err. i follow : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#dropping-indexes

```
Schema::table('stack_links', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropUnique(['url']);
            $table->dropIndex(['url']);

            $table->text('url')->change();
            $table->string('md5_url');

            $table->unique('md5_url');
            $table->index('md5_url');
        });
```

Can anyone tell me where am i wrong.

**Update** : The problem is the parameter of dropIndex. When i replace it with the name of index. It work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length
follow this i think this will help you.

Comment: @KuldeepMishra i have removed index, but it still log the same err

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations
have you checked this link ??

Comment: Man, using `unique` on that `url` is going to be super costly for you in the future if you start dealing with tons of records. Now, regarding your problem, you absolutely must use a `length` on a `text` column when you want it to be an `index`. so... `$table->text('url', 1024)->change()` for instance.

Comment: @KuldeepMishra just write out what i should correct , please don't write the link, because i have read it, but maybe i have not understand enough

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: i know, but in this case, i don't want to limit the length of url, also remove all index on url. i want index on md5_url

Comment: @NgoTuan try DB::statement()

Answer (score 1):

Try `DB Statement` -

```
 public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE stack_links DROP INDEX stack_links_url_index');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE stack_links MODIFY COLUMN url TEXT');
}
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE stack_links CREATE INDEX stack_links_url_index');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE stack_links MODIFY COLUMN url STRING');
}
```