# Migration error in django using MySql db

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

I have downloaded Mayan EDMS-Electronic Document Management System from GitHub and I configured project using Django server. I had added the required libraries based on requirement. when I tried to migrate Django using Mysql server, I got the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'value' used in key specification without a key length")
```

When I searched this error, I found  -->[MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length). but I occur error while migration.

django version - 1.11.5,

mysql version - 5.7.20

please help me to find the problem. thanks in advance