# 1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'XXX' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql, sql

This error happens when I use long as primary key to create table. I've already checked [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length) but I think it does not solve my problem since I'm not using text or blob as index.

I can not figure out why `long weng_id` as primary key but it shows `BLOB/TEXT column weng_id`

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `ContentRepository`.`无标题`  (
  `weng_id` long NOT NULL,
  `content_type` tinyint(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `store_time` datetime(0) NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
  `create_time` datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `modify_time` datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `weng_url` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `algorithm_tags` varchar(1000) NULL,
  `words` varchar(1000) NULL,
  `operate_tags` varchar(1000) NULL,
  `mdd_id` bigint(0) NULL,
  `related_mdd_ids` varchar(1000) NULL,
  `related_pois` varchar(1000) NULL,
  `uid` bigint(0) NOT NULL,
  `user_level` tinyint(0) NOT NULL,
  `user_contribution_score` double NULL,
  `status` tinyint(0) NOT NULL,
  `check_status` tinyint(0) NULL,
  `checked_time` datetime(0) NULL,
  `static_score` double NULL,
  `static_level` int(0) NULL,
  `dynamic_level` int(0) NULL,
  `dynamic_score` double NULL,
  `show_channel` int(0) NULL,
  `show_num` bigint(0) NULL,
  `click_num` bigint(0) NULL,
  `favorite_num` bigint(0) NOT NULL,
  `comment_num` bigint(0) NOT NULL,
  `share_num` bigint(0) NOT NULL,
  `collect_num` bigint(0) NOT NULL,
  `weng_type` tinyint(0) NOT NULL,
  `pricture_urls` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `video_url` varchar(1000) NULL,
  `content` varchar(8000) NULL,
  `weng_level` tinyint(0) NOT NULL,
  `weng_category` tinyint(0) NOT NULL,
  `picture_num` int(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`weng_id`),
  INDEX `idx_create`(`create_time`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `idx_modify`(`modify_time`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `idx_store`(`store_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` is probably not the type you think it is.  You probably want `bigint`:

```
CREATE TABLE `ContentRepository`.`无标题`  (
  `weng_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `content_type` tinyint(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   . . .
)
```

`long` is a large string (`mediumtext`).  It is not suitable for indexing in general.

Comment: Thanks. Did not notice that.