# "BLOB/TEXT column used in key specification without a key length" error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.2, django-mysql

I have this model in my Django project:

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I run my project completely when I use `SQLite` ,but when I change my database engine to `Mysql` I got this error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length")
```

***What I must to do?***

Comment: I had `unique=True,` in my `name` field and when I delete that, Error has been gone, But I don't know the reason!

Comment: See here for an explanation :-): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was trying to create an index for a `TextField`. I didn't notice I had used  `TextField` for my `name` field, I was supposed to use `CharField`.

```
class myModel(models): 
    name = models.TextField(max_length=80)
   
    class Meta:                                                                                                                              
        indexes = [ models.Index(fields=['name'])]
```

Here was my solution.

First, I deleted the migration file created when I added an index in my model for the first time and run `python manage.py makemigrations`

Second, I removed the index from my model.

```
class myModel(models): 
    name = models.TextField(max_length=80)
```

Third, I run `python manage.py makemigrations`. It showed "no changes detected".

Fourth, I run `python manage.py migrate` and I did not get the error again.

To successfully create the index, I had to change the `TextField` field to `CharField` and add the index again.

```
class myModel(models): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   
    class Meta:                                                                                                                              
        indexes = [ models.Index(fields=['name'])]
```

Running `makemigrations` and `migrate` went fine and created the index successfully.