# How to add unique constraint to big textfield in django?

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

models.py:

```
class PageURL(models.Model):
    url = models.TextField(max_length=2048, unique=True)
```

Error during migrations:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'url' used
>   in key specification without a key length")

I considered a CharField but Django said the max on that for this use case was 255 characters. Initially I just had `TextField(unique=True)` but decided to add a max_length which I heard was normally 2048 for URLs but that hasn't helped silence the errors.

I tried CharField with no max_length and just a unique constraint set.

> core.PageURL.url: (fields.E120) CharFields must define a 'max_length'
>   attribute. core.PageURL.url: (mysql.E001) MySQL does not allow unique
>   CharFields to have a max_length > 255.

The solution I've rigged is to go into phpMyAdmin and alter the structure by hand to varchar(2048) and add a unique constraint to it.

Answer (score 2):

Unique constraints aren't possible with a MySQL `BLOB/TEXT` column.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length) question for a detailed explanation on that.

To address the migration lock you are in, you will need to rollback your migration to the point before you tried to add a `unique=True` constraint to the `url` field.  Look through `myapp/migrations` for this model, and see when that was exactly.
The file should look something like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (<myapp>, <migration name>),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='PageURL',
            name='url',
            field=models.TextField(max_length=2048, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Now, from the command line, run `python3 manage.py migrate <myapp> <migration name>`

Lastly, delete all the migrations that came after `<migration name>`.

### Edit

I figured I should at least attempt to give you a solution for your specific case, although I don't know what that model is used for exactly.

If you want to have a unique url column, you can try a `FK` relation like this:

```
class Url(models.Model):
    protocol = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sld = models.CharField(max_length=2048, unique=True)
    tld = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('protocol', 'sld', 'tld'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.protocol}://{self.sld}.{self.tld}'
```

Now on any models that need a `url` column, you can do something like this instead:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(Url, related_name='url_path', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    url_path = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_url(self):
        return f'{self.url}/{self.url_path}'
```