# Django can not create test database using MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm developing a large Django project and I'm beginning to write some tests. But I ran into a problem when running them. When I run `python manage.py test` I get the following error:

```sh
$ project/ python manage.py test
                    project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:319: RuntimeWarning: Model 'accounts.manager' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.
  new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_partyadvisor'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_partyadvisor', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 312, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'content' used in key specification without a key length")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 62, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 601, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 546, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 187, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 69, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 131, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 97, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 319, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 136, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 312, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'content' used in key specification without a key length")
```

The test database is created, but for some reason I can not use it (?).
My database configuration is, (in the `settings.py` file):

```py
DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
            "HOST": env.get("database").get("HOST"),
            "PORT": env.get("database").get("PORT"),
            "NAME": env.get("database").get("NAME"),
            "USER": env.get("database").get("USER"),
            "PASSWORD": env.get("database").get("PASS")
        }
}
```

Notes:

1. The user I use to access the db has all grants on it.
2. I tried to run the tests using the root user, and got the same error.
3. The normal db and the cache one work perfectly.
4. Also ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`.
5. Deleted the test db from MySQL shell and re-run `python manage.py test`, got the same error.
6. Option `--keep-db` not working either.

System is Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm using Django 1.11 and MySQL 5.7.

Comment: you have created your models in model.py ?

Comment: @FarhaniWalid yes, as I said the normal env is working fine

Comment: [interlinguex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13077826) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278890) saying "A rather detailed comment concerning this error message, `1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'content' used in key specification without a key length"` , has been posted on stackexchange (see [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length))  Would that help solve the issue in your case?"