# Laravel QueryException when adding unique constraint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I want to create a "users" table with the email record as a unique value with the Migrations file of my Laravel project

```php
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->string('company')->nullable();
      $table->string('street', 80)->nullable();
      $table->string('zip', 10)->nullable();
      $table->string('city', 80)->nullable();
      $table->string('country', 3)->nullable();
      $table->string('firstname', 80)->nullable();
      $table->string('lastname', 80)->nullable();
      $table->string('email', 80);
      $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
      $table->string('password');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
```

works fine, but if I replace `$table->string('email', 80);` with `$table->string('email', 80)->unique();` I get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: alter table` users`add unique`users_email_unique`(`email`))` 
 I read, that adding `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` in AppServiceProvider.php would solve this, but even after adding it
 and clearing cache with `php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear` the error is still there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] Connection refused within Laravel homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead)

Comment: @WahyuKristianto sadly not, the connection gets established and the table is beeing created, the error only occurs when trying to set "email" to unique. I can connect fine to the database

Comment: do you have data in table or its newly created table ?

Comment: @AqibJaved it is a newly created table, without any data inside of it

Comment: try after clearing config php artisan config:clear

Comment: I cleared config, cache, view and route with `php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear`, didnt change anything, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bit more I realised, that the error was with my mariadb version, as pointed out in [this Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60765913/15060496) MariaDB 10.4 supports a UNIQUE KEY on a TEXT column, so I changed `$table->string('email')->unique()` to `$table->text('email')->unique()` and it worked.