# django.db.utils.OperationalError: 1170

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm doing my own server using `python-virtualenv, django, nginx, uwsgi`.
Django database is mysql. when i migrate django project on virtualenv, always

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: 
(1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'credential_id_data' used 
in key specification without a key length")
```

this error came out.
i don't know why this error happened. when I google, someone said in model.py, TextField is not good, use Charfield.
but my code is charfield... i don't know why this error happend.

Here is the model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import(BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    def create_user(self, username, userid, company, companycode, password=None):

        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an name!'))

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company= company,
            companycode = companycode,
        )
        user.set_password(companycode) #usrid를 암호화
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, userid, company, companycode, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            userid = userid,
            company = company,
            companycode = companycode,
            password=password,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name="이름")
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name="아이디")
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="회사")
    companycode = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="회사코드")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="생성날짜")
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['userid', 'company', 'companycode']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All superusers are staff
        return self.is_superuser

    get_full_name.short_description = _('Full name')
```

and this is error

```
  Applying django_fido.0010_credential_id_not_null...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'credential_id_data' used in key specification without a key length")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 566, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 747, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_unique_sql(model, [new_field.column]))
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'credential_id_data' used in key specification without a key length")
```

Comment: The error seems to be in the `django_fido` package

Comment: then, delete django_fido?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length)