# Can MariaDB index on BLOB column without a key length or not?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I executed the same statement on two instances of MariaDB, one got an error and the other didn't.

The statement I executed is:

```
CREATE TABLE `session_tokens` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `token` blob NOT NULL,
  `inserted_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_tokens_token_index` (`token`) USING HASH,
  KEY `session_tokens_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `session_tokens_user_id_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hashed_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `inserted_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_login_name_index` (`login_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Error message displayed:

```
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'token' used in key specification without a key length
```

The versions of the two instances are the same.

```
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

The OS of the instance with the error is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS running on Google Cloud Platform. The OS of the other instance is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) running on the local Docker.

According to [the discussions already made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length), it seems correct that the error occurs.

Please let me know if you have any clues as to why this difference occurs.

Comment: Can you double-check the version? MariaDB since 10.4.3 allows indexes on blobs. (Actually, even if the docker version shows 10.3., I would expect it to not actually be 10.3. and/or have 10.4. changes downported. Check if there is information about that included for your docker container)

Comment: @Solarflare Ah, you are right! The actual version of the second instance is 10.5.9. I was mistakenly looking at the version number reported by the mariadb client.