# Generate random numeric id as a column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a random numeric Pandas series and assign to the DataFrame. My DataFrame has an `id` column, however, it is alphanumeric which causes some issues when doing querying the data from a SQL database.

Therefore, I'd like to create a randomly generated numeric column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'id': [1, 2, 3] 
                 })
```

The randomly generated numeric `id` column should be of length 6.

Expected output:

```
name  id  rid
A     1   731721
B     2   831273
C     3   831212
```

Comment: Why a random ID - as long as it's unique - why does randomness matter (plus it's more work when you want to add any new rows - as you've gotta check you haven't already picked that random id etc...) - also - what issues is an alphanumeric ID causing - it's just a column...!?

Comment: I don't know SQL, but this sounds like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). Maybe the real issue is that your database setup can't handle alphanumeric IDs.

Comment: @JonClements good point. It doesn't have to be random I guess. I am unable to set the Alphanumeric ID as PK in MySQL without adding additional complexity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length#:~:text=Sometimes%2C%20even%20though%20you%20don,its%20length%20or%20characters%20size

Comment: @kms so - can you (optionally) keep a unique constraint on the existing column and alter the table to have a new bigint auto incrementing primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Generate random sample between 100000 and 999999 with `DataFrame` shape

```
import random
df['rid'] = random.sample(range(100000, 999999), df.shape[0])
  name  id     rid
0    A   1  953858
1    B   2  244870
2    C   3  306826
```