# I cannot make MySQL column values unique, Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I try to make a column value, unique = true I get the following error.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table student 
       add constraint UK_fe0i52si7ybu0wjedj6motiim unique (email)" via JDBC Statement
....
....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'email' used in key specification without a key length
```

This is my application properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/dataJpaDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.error.include-message=always
```

I'm using MySQL version 8.

This is my entity class

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "first_name",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String firstName;

    @Column(
            name = "last_name",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String lastName;

    @Column(
            name = "email",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition="TEXT",
            unique = true /// this is causing the problem
    )
    private String email;

    @Column(
            name = "age",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "INTEGER"
    )
    private Integer age;

    public Student(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

When I remove the "unique = true" everything seems to work fine.
What is causing this problem and how to resolve it.

P.S. sorry for the long post.

Comment: You are likely adding the "unique" key as a property of the field (as per your framework). You probably need to find how to add an "index" (of type unique) to a field, from your framework. I am assuming it would start with say "@index" instead of "@column". Your framework documentation (Spring) would have it prescribed.

Comment: I'm following along a video tutorial for this and in the video, it worked smoothly, however they used PostgreSQL, does that make a different?

Comment: Most likely, it shouldn't be a problem. Most frameworks use same syntax for different backend sql variations.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length

Answer (score 1):

When you specify that a field must be unique, Hibernate ORM creates a constraint on the database.
But different databases might have different requirements about the creation of the constraint based on the column definition.

Checking the MySQL website about [BLOB and Text types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html):

> For indexes on BLOB and TEXT columns, you must specify an index prefix length.

The easiest solution is not to touch the columnDefinition attribute:

```
   @Column( name = "email",
            nullable = false,
            unique = true)
    private String email
```

Not sure why you specify it, but you should only use that attribute if you want to define a column using a type that's different from the default used by Hibernate ORM. In this case the column will be a `varchar(255)` and everything will work fine.

If you want the column to be a `TEXT` and you still want to create the schema using Hibernate ORM, you could add the constraint creation in the `import.sql` (and remove the attribute `unique=true`).
Hibernate ORM will execute the content of that file after the schema has been created and if you include the following query in it, it will create the constraint:

```
alter table Student add constraint my_unique_constraint unique (email(10))
```

I will let you to the Hibernate ORM guide for more details about [schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-script-files)

Keep in mind that this last solution is not portable and you will have to update the constraint creation query every time you change database (or the attribute name).

PS: I'm talking about Hibernate ORM in this answer but I should have used JPA or Spring Data. Anyway, everything still applies.